# Xamarin and Visual Studio 2015 issues with building a solution

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

Since I updated to Xamarin 4.0.3.214 and Visual Studio 2015 with Update 2, when I try to build a solution, it gives me this error:

> 1. System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path
>          'C:\ProgramData\Mono for Android\License\monoandroid.licx' is
>          denied. at
>          Xamarin.Components.Ide.Activation.ActivationService.GetErrorWorkflow(LicenseSyncResult[]
>          results, Boolean ignoreSyncErrors) at
>          Xamarin.Components.Ide.Activation.ActivationService.d__59.MoveNext()
>          at
>          Xamarin.Components.Ide.Activation.ActivationDialog.DisplayWorkflowStep(ActivationWorkflowStep
>          step) at
>          Xamarin.Components.Ide.Activation.ActivationDialog.<>c__DisplayClass31_0.b__0(Task t)

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by replacing two files in /android and /ios folders

> mandroid.exe and mtouch.exe

Not sure what went wrong, but after all glad to get it working once again
Now I'm able to r/e/build delpoy and clean solutions

Thank you